# Table column sizing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

In `Bootstrap 3`,  I could apply `col-sm-xx` to the `th` tags in the `thead` and resize table columns at will. However this doesn't work in bootstrap 4. How can I achieve something like this in bootstrap 4?

```
<thead>
<th class="col-sm-3">3 columns wide</th>
<th class="col-sm-5">5 columns wide</th>
<th class="col-sm-4">4 columns wide</th>
</thead>
```

Looking at the codeply provided it doesn't size properly, especially if you add some data to the table. See how this runs:

```
<div class="container" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr class="row">
            <th class="col-sm-3">3 columns wide</th>
            <th class="col-sm-5">5 columns wide</th>
            <th class="col-sm-4">4 columns wide</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>123</td>
            <td>456</td>
            <td>789</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: as an addendum to this question: if you have long content (such as very long URLs) to display the bootstrap 4 tables aren't a great solution even with the sizing answer below. either using a flex-row or row/col solution tends to work better with overflow and text-wrap

Answer (score 181, accepted):

**Updated 2018**

Make sure your table includes the `table` class. This is because [Bootstrap 4 tables are "opt-in"](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/) so the `table` class must be intentionally added to the table.

http://codeply.com/go/zJLXypKZxL

Bootstrap 3.x also had some CSS to reset the table cells so that they don't float..

```
table td[class*=col-], table th[class*=col-] {
    position: static;
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
}
```

I don't know why this isn't is Bootstrap 4 alpha, but it may be added back in the final release. Adding this CSS will help all columns to use the widths set in the `thead`..

[Bootstrap 4 Alpha 2 Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/AUwbs5WRMs)

---

**UPDATE (as of Bootstrap 4.0.0)**

Now that Bootstrap 4 is flexbox, the table cells will not assume the correct width when adding `col-*`. A workaround is to use the `d-inline-block` class on the table cells to prevent the default display:flex of columns.

Another option in BS4 is to use the sizing utils classes for width...

```
<thead>
     <tr>
           <th class="w-25">25</th>
           <th class="w-50">50</th>
           <th class="w-25">25</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/BYrG9NNd6e)

Lastly, you could use `d-flex` on the table rows (tr), and the `col-*` grid classes on the columns (th,td)...

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <th class="col-3">25%</th>
                <th class="col-3">25%</th>
                <th class="col-6">50%</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="d-flex">
                <td class="col-sm-3">..</td>
                <td class="col-sm-3">..</td>
                <td class="col-sm-6">..</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

[**Bootstrap 4.0.0 (stable) Demo**](https://www.codeply.com/go/NYiFymzRkj)

Note: Changing the TR to display:flex [can alter the borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51840249/bootstrap-4-table-with-d-flex-and-another-border-color/51841018#51841018)

Comment: Actually that doesn't size properly. Check it out if you add some borders to see how the sizing is and when you add a row to the body. I put the code up in the question

Comment: Actually your BS4-A6 example doesn't work if you have overflowing content in a column since the other columns aren't extended. Try pasting some lorem ipsum in one column.

Comment: Your solution worked. In my case, I needed to add no-gutters in the tr to avoid negative padding https://jsfiddle.net/Vimalan/xhvdcasn/

Comment: Yes, the `w-25`, `w-50`, and `w-75` classes work with bootstrap 4. Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

Another option is to apply flex styling at the table row, and add the `col-classes` to the table header / table data elements:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <th class="col-3">3 columns wide header</th>
      <th class="col-sm-5">5 columns wide header</th>
      <th class="col-sm-4">4 columns wide header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <td class="col-3">3 columns wide content</th>
      <td class="col-sm-5">5 columns wide content</th>
      <td class="col-sm-4">4 columns wide content</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works but `vertical-align: middle` doesn't work anymore with `d-flex` class.

Comment: Vertical alignment does indeed not work on flexbox layout. Use `align-items: baseline`. To learn more about flexbox, read this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)

Comment: Exactly this is THE solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Using `d-flex` class works well but some other attributes don't work anymore like `vertical-align: middle` property.

The best way I found to size columns very easily is to use the `width` attribute with percentage only in `thead` cells.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">25%</th>
            <th width="25%">25%</th>
            <th width="50%">50%</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>25%</td>
            <td>25%</td>
            <td>50%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: **Note** Using width attribute for <th> is now **not supported** in **HTML5**

Answer (score 11):

I hacked this out for release Bootstrap 4.1.1 per my needs before I saw @florian_korner's post.  Looks very similar.

If you use sass you can paste this snippet at the end of your bootstrap includes.   It seems to fix the issue for chrome, IE, and edge.  Does not seem to break anything in firefox.

```
@mixin make-td-col($size, $columns: $grid-columns) {
    width: percentage($size / $columns);
}

@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

    @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
        td.col#{$infix}-#{$i}, th.col#{$infix}-#{$i} {
            @include make-td-col($i, $grid-columns);
        }
    }
}
```

or if you just want the compiled css utility:

```
td.col-1, th.col-1 {
  width: 8.33333%; }

td.col-2, th.col-2 {
  width: 16.66667%; }

td.col-3, th.col-3 {
  width: 25%; }

td.col-4, th.col-4 {
  width: 33.33333%; }

td.col-5, th.col-5 {
  width: 41.66667%; }

td.col-6, th.col-6 {
  width: 50%; }

td.col-7, th.col-7 {
  width: 58.33333%; }

td.col-8, th.col-8 {
  width: 66.66667%; }

td.col-9, th.col-9 {
  width: 75%; }

td.col-10, th.col-10 {
  width: 83.33333%; }

td.col-11, th.col-11 {
  width: 91.66667%; }

td.col-12, th.col-12 {
  width: 100%; }

td.col-sm-1, th.col-sm-1 {
  width: 8.33333%; }

td.col-sm-2, th.col-sm-2 {
  width: 16.66667%; }

td.col-sm-3, th.col-sm-3 {
  width: 25%; }

td.col-sm-4, th.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33333%; }

td.col-sm-5, th.col-sm-5 {
  width: 41.66667%; }

td.col-sm-6, th.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%; }

td.col-sm-7, th.col-sm-7 {
  width: 58.33333%; }

td.col-sm-8, th.col-sm-8 {
  width: 66.66667%; }

td.col-sm-9, th.col-sm-9 {
  width: 75%; }

td.col-sm-10, th.col-sm-10 {
  width: 83.33333%; }

td.col-sm-11, th.col-sm-11 {
  width: 91.66667%; }

td.col-sm-12, th.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%; }

td.col-md-1, th.col-md-1 {
  width: 8.33333%; }

td.col-md-2, th.col-md-2 {
  width: 16.66667%; }

td.col-md-3, th.col-md-3 {
  width: 25%; }

td.col-md-4, th.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.33333%; }

td.col-md-5, th.col-md-5 {
  width: 41.66667%; }

td.col-md-6, th.col-md-6 {
  width: 50%; }

td.col-md-7, th.col-md-7 {
  width: 58.33333%; }

td.col-md-8, th.col-md-8 {
  width: 66.66667%; }

td.col-md-9, th.col-md-9 {
  width: 75%; }

td.col-md-10, th.col-md-10 {
  width: 83.33333%; }

td.col-md-11, th.col-md-11 {
  width: 91.66667%; }

td.col-md-12, th.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%; }

td.col-lg-1, th.col-lg-1 {
  width: 8.33333%; }

td.col-lg-2, th.col-lg-2 {
  width: 16.66667%; }

td.col-lg-3, th.col-lg-3 {
  width: 25%; }

td.col-lg-4, th.col-lg-4 {
  width: 33.33333%; }

td.col-lg-5, th.col-lg-5 {
  width: 41.66667%; }

td.col-lg-6, th.col-lg-6 {
  width: 50%; }

td.col-lg-7, th.col-lg-7 {
  width: 58.33333%; }

td.col-lg-8, th.col-lg-8 {
  width: 66.66667%; }

td.col-lg-9, th.col-lg-9 {
  width: 75%; }

td.col-lg-10, th.col-lg-10 {
  width: 83.33333%; }

td.col-lg-11, th.col-lg-11 {
  width: 91.66667%; }

td.col-lg-12, th.col-lg-12 {
  width: 100%; }

td.col-xl-1, th.col-xl-1 {
  width: 8.33333%; }

td.col-xl-2, th.col-xl-2 {
  width: 16.66667%; }

td.col-xl-3, th.col-xl-3 {
  width: 25%; }

td.col-xl-4, th.col-xl-4 {
  width: 33.33333%; }

td.col-xl-5, th.col-xl-5 {
  width: 41.66667%; }

td.col-xl-6, th.col-xl-6 {
  width: 50%; }

td.col-xl-7, th.col-xl-7 {
  width: 58.33333%; }

td.col-xl-8, th.col-xl-8 {
  width: 66.66667%; }

td.col-xl-9, th.col-xl-9 {
  width: 75%; }

td.col-xl-10, th.col-xl-10 {
  width: 83.33333%; }

td.col-xl-11, th.col-xl-11 {
  width: 91.66667%; }

td.col-xl-12, th.col-xl-12 {
  width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: This answer may be a bit old. Since the bootstrap 4 beta. Bootstrap has changed since then.

The table column size class has been changed from this

```
<th class="col-sm-3">3 columns wide</th>
```

to

```
<th class="col-3">3 columns wide</th>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in setting the column widths: http://www.codeply.com/go/Utyon2XEB6

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: The other question is unrelated. The colums widths don't work on table cells because of BS4 alpha 6 flexbox as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I can resolve this problem using the following code using Bootstrap 4:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="d-flex">
      <th class="col-3" scope="row">Indicador:</th>
      <td class="col-9">this is my indicator</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="d-flex">
      <th class="col-3" scope="row">Definición:</th>
      <td class="col-9">This is my definition</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Alpha 6 you can create the following sass file:

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints);

  col, td, th {
    @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
        &.col#{$infix}-#{$i} {
          flex: none;
          position: initial;
        }
    }

    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $grid-breakpoints) {
      @for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
        &.col#{$infix}-#{$i} {
          width: 100% / $grid-columns * $i;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this code don't work at all - tried to debug it for 1.5 hours but my knowledge of sass is too weak to do that. Plz post working examples next time.