# How do I hide a cell border in a Bootstrap 4 table?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This question is a follow-up to a question I read called '[bootstrap 4 table column sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924104/bootstrap-4-table-column-sizing)'.

I want to create a small table (2x3) with the outside border of the bottom-right cell missing. The picture should explain it. Does anyone know how I can do this on Bootstrap 4?

[2x3 table with bottom-right cell hidden/missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CHCH.jpg)

One user on the aforementioned question created a 2x3 table on Copeply. I'm using this code as a template. The link is here: https://www.codeply.com/go/BYrG9NNd6e

In short, can anyone tell me how to add to this code in order to hide the outside border of the bottom-right cell?

I'm very new to coding. Apologies for any basic errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `table-bordered` in this case because it creates a border around the entire table. You could create a custom class like this...

```
.table-custom td, .table-custom th {
    border:1px #eee solid;
}
/* remove border from bottom right cell */
.table-custom tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border:none;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/ZmMzQ1OHE5

Comment: That's fantastic. Thanks so much.