# Table column width with Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

This is my first question in StackOverflow, because it's the first time I haven't been able to find an answer that helped me solve my problem.
I'm trying to make a table for a menu with bootstrap. I want the breakfast, lunch and dinner columns width to be 30% each and the one saying carbs, fat and proteins 10% but I cannot make it work.
I read through [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/) and actually found a pretty similar quiestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924104/bootstrap-4-table-column-sizing). However, I still cannot make it work. 
I put my code [here in CodePen](https://codepen.io/KrakenWhisperer/pen/MQymeg) so you can see what I'm seeing.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="m-0">
      <th class="w-10">#</th>
      <th class="w-30">Breakfast</th>
      <th class="w-30">Lunch</th>
      <th class="w-30">Dinner</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="m-0">
      <th scope="row" class="w-10">Carbohydrates</th>
      <td class="w-30">-
      </td>
      <td class="w-30">
        -
      </td>
      <td class="w-30">-
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="m-0">
      <th scope="row" class="w-10">Fat</th>
      <td class="w-30">-
      </td>
      <td class="w-30">
        -
      </td>
      <td class="w-30">-
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="m-0">
      <th scope="row" class="w-10">Proteins</th>
      <td class="w-30">-
      </td>
      <td class="w-30">
        -
      </td>
      <td class="w-30">-
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me spot what I'm missing? I've just been learning to code on my own for about 3 months and started with bootstrap last week, so I hope it isn't something very obvious.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to provide CSS rules

```
table .w-10 { width:10%; }
table .w-30 { width:30%; }
```

Note that Bootstrap does come with [some predefined width classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/), but only for multiples of 25%.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`style="width:30%"` or 10%
for each th element.

Check here for more info:
[Bootstrap - how to set up fixed width for <td>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115052/bootstrap-how-to-set-up-fixed-width-for-td)

Comment: No, don't do this. Don't hack your styles into your HTML. That is what CSS is for: **style sheets**