# Table Td width always 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, bootstrap-4

I'd like to specify a width for the whole column based on TH.
As you can see:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 50px">TEST 50</th>
      <th style="width: 100px">TEST 100</th>
      <th style="width: 150px">TEST 150</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input class"form-control" typ="text"></td>
      <td><input class"form-control" typ="text"></td>
      <td><input class"form-control" typ="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/148760/

It always gets 100%.

How could I have a table with 3 columns with 50px, 100px and 150px width.3.
I use bootstrap4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 tables are always `width:100%`. You can use the `w-auto` util class on the table to make it `width:auto;`

Make sure the HTML is properly structured.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered w-auto">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:50px">TEST 50</th>
          <th style="width:100px">TEST 100</th>
          <th style="width:150px">TEST 150</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/ONEQJYeJPN

---

Related: [bootstrap 4 table column sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924104/bootstrap-4-table-column-sizing/37928581#37928581)